# Expected time of a low chance event

Tags: probability

If a low chance event has a probability p = 0.0001% chance to happen every second.  What is the expected time for the event to happen once? Does the answer change if the event has p = 0.0001% chance to happen every millisecond?

Attempt: Find $t$ such that $(1 - p)^t$ is close to 0.

$(1 - p)$ is 0.999999. 0.999999^5000000 = 0.0067. So the expected time is about 5 million seconds or milliseconds.

Comment: Are these independent trials?  If so, the expected number of trials needs to get the first success is $\frac 1p$.   See the [Geometric Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution)

Comment: Yes, they are independent trials.

Comment: To get close to $0$ you just have to make $t$ large because the limit for $t\to \infty$ is clearly $0$